# PHP INSERT en MY SQL campo decimal

Tags: php, html, mysql

seguro es algo basico pero me tiene varado, mi tabla MySQL espera un dato de tipo decimal(10,3) el mismo lo tengo que enviar desde un formulario el cual es un input Type NUM y step 0.02 para dejarme ingresar numeros de hasta 3 decimales (?) y por otro lado les dejo mi código en php. espero me puedan ayudar a detectar mi error. ya que al enviar esto campos vacios me da el mensaje del or die () "imposible conectar".

```
    $decimal= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST['decimal'], ENT_QUOTES)));

$insert = mysqli_query($DB, "INSERT INTO CCVALOR(decimal)VALUES('$decimal')")or die("imposible conectar");

 <form name="form1" id="form1" action="registro.php" method="POST" >
    <label for="decimal">decimal</label>
   <input name="decimal" id="decimal" type="number" step="0.02" placeholder="decimal">
```

Comment: No entendí cuál es el error que tienes.

Comment: basicamente es que no me esta dejando enviar los decimales algo debo tener mal en como transformo la variable obtenida por POST antes de enviarla a la DB por el insert.

Comment: No te faltó cerrar una comilla doble en tu INSERT?

Comment: Hola Gracias por querer ayudarme, te pido perdon pero copie con errores el codigo aca en el foro, ahi ya los corregi mi errror digo que esta aca en esta linea : 
$decimal= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST['decimal'], ENT_QUOTES)));

Comment: Tu error es probable que esté en '$decimal' debería de ser $decimal sin las comillas simples porque si no mysql entiende que intentas insertar un varchar en un campo que evidentemente es de tipo decimal.

Comment: nono, cuando obtienes la variable por POST[aca adentro va con comillas]

Comment: Me refiero a que cambies tu insert de estar así `INSERT INTO CCVALOR(decimal)VALUES('$decimal')` a esto `INSERT INTO CCVALOR(decimal)VALUES($decimal)` por lo que antes te expliqué

Comment: Bien ahi ya lo hice e hice tambien un var_dump de la variable para ver que es lo que arroja y es esto: C:\wamp64\www\Aranceles\registro.php:38:string '' (length=0)

Comment: el problema va por ahi, esta tomando string en vez de un decimal, aunque ya hice lo que me dijiste de las comillas.

Comment: Hazle dentro de tu código php un echo a esa consulta del insert, tómala y pégala dentro de tu phpmyadmin, lo que salga, es el error que nos interesa saber. También me interesa saber qué INSERT te genera.

Comment: Fernando ya lo solucione gracias a vos me fltaba edita uno de los campos obligatorios, (sacarle las comillas) y el step 0.02 tenia que ser step 0.001, muchas gracias por todo colega.